# Button.OnCommand += new CommandEventHandler Results in protection level error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does below code result in the following error:

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    UpdatePanel updatePanel;
    ...
    Button moreButton = new Button();
    moreButton.ID = "moreButton";
    moreButton.Text = "More";
    updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(moreButton);
    moreButton.CommandName = "More";
    moreButton.CommandArgument = department.ID + "|department";
    moreButton.OnCommand += new CommandEventHandler(getMoreInfoCommand_Click);
    ...
    updatePanelList.Add(updatePanel);
}


protected void getMoreInfoCommand_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use

```
moreButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(getMoreInfoCommand_Click);
```

`OnCommand` is a protected *method*, while `Command` is a public *event*.

Comment: Thanks I knew it was going to be something easy.